# Vagrant for development and CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, vagrant, chef-infra

I would like to setup the following workflow.

- Each project has a Vagrant file under version control and a Jenkins job that builds the virtual machine for every configuration change. This virtual machine is meant to be used both for continuous integration and development.
- A developer joins a project. He grabs the corresponding virtual machine from Jenkins which is all setup and configured.
- He runs the virtual machine he downloaded. All his preferences eg. .gitconfig .vimrc etc. are already in his home directory on that virtual machine, I.e. he uses the virtual machine to code, not just to run and test.
- When the project's build job under Jenkins detects a change in the repository, it grabs the virtual machine as an artefact from the same job the developer used and runs the build

This would allow new devs to be ready to code in minutes in exactly the same environment the continuous integration server uses and deploy anywhere thanks to the virtual machine.

I thought I might try this with Vagrant and Chef but I'm not sure they're really meant to be used like that. Any thoughts?

Comment: I dont understand why you need to start the VM from the developer ? I mean all VM are supposed to be the same - there is a jenkins vagrant plugin but you seem to add some more logic than needed from my point of view

Comment: So each developer has their own copy of the same exact environment. They can work offline for example.

Comment: clear, but all VM are the same, its the point to use vagrant, you start from the same box and apply the same provisioning so jenkins would start a VM from the same Vagrantfile and they will all be identical

Comment: They will all be identical for one project but they can differ from one project to another. And a project's need (library versions, compiler etc.) can evolve. Do you mean all developers should login to the same virtual machine?

Comment: no each developer has its own VM. the VM will differ for each project but you will have different Vagrantfile per project and you can run multiple VM from the same host - your jenkins job is done per project or manages multiple project ?

Comment: Per project. The Vagrant file is under version control. Not quite sure where to put it actually: if it's in the project repo any commit to the project will trigger a useless build of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each project has a Vagrant file under version control and a Jenkins
>   job that builds the virtual machine for every configuration change.
>   This virtual machine is meant to be used both for continuous
>   integration and development.

A Vagrantfile defines whats your application environment should look like.
Along with provisioning (Chef, Puppet, Ansible or Shell ...) you will create exact same VM for each team members that are working on your project.
You do not then need to create the VM and use the same instance of the VM from CI or developers. Each would have their own environment.

> A developer joins a project. He grabs the corresponding virtual
>   machine from Jenkins which is all setup and configured.

Each developer will launch a VM running on their laptop from the same Vagrantfile - no need to share VMs.

> When the project's build job under Jenkins detects a change in the
>   repository, it grabs the virtual machine as an artefact from the same
>   job the developer used and runs the build

You can use the [Jenkins vagrant-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant-plugin) to start a VM from the same Vagrantfile that corresponds to your project. You will not run the job from an existing VM.

Note: If you worry that the provisioning would take too much time and thats why you say you want to use existing VM, you can create a new box with all your dependencies installed and repackage to use that as the new base box

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wasn't very clear: when I say "the virtual machine" I mean "any clone of the virtual machine", not " the same instance ". The important thing is that the environment is identical for CI and development. The idea of grabbing a VM from Jenkins was that it saves the developer from having Vagrant installed. He/she just gets the virtual disk and runs it: no need to regenerate the VM. Jenkins can send an email to tell the devs to update their VM if the Vagrant file changes. I didn't understand your last sentence: how do I repackage?

Comment: honestly I think if you plan to use VM, vagrant is a bit plus to manage those for the developers. shared folders, ssh, reload. `The important thing is that the environment is identical for CI and development` yes Vagrantfile + provisioning will assure that. you can read more [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html) about the vagrant box and the (re)packaging